# iOS (14): UMP SDK implemented -> AppTrackingTransparency framework still necessary?

Tags: ios, apptrackingtransparency

Google has sent us a lot of different emails to the topic "prepare your app for iOS 14+" and I am a bit confused.

We have now implemented the UMP sdk according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start) to show an ad-consent form connected to our Funding Choices account.

Is it still necessary to configure a NSUserTrackingUsageDescription and call the `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` method from the AppTrackingTransparency framework?

[Here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/ios/quick-start#app_tracking_transparency) they describe how to configure the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription in the Info.plist, so it sounds to me, that I have to show the consent using the UMP sdk AND the Apple App Transparency dialog afterwards.... but why should the user have to agree twice for the same thing?

Comment: `AppTrackingTransparency` is a iOS native dialog for ad consent, like location/camera/microphone etc. So yes, it's necessary.

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen thanks. Do I have to show show this native iOS dialog manually or does the UMP sdk care for that? The docs sound like it will be donw automatically when defining the NSUserTrackingUsageDescription within Info.plist, but at the end, only the consent form from Funding Choices is shown.

Comment: According to the SDK the system dialog will be presented by UMP if you define the `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription`. But you could, you know, try it and see? :) After all you shouldn't ship anything you haven't tested

Comment: Well, guess what, I tried it and I do not see the native dialog, even with NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, so I was not sure if this is expected or if it should work automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it still necessary to configure a NSUserTrackingUsageDescription

Yes, you need to add `NSUserTrackingUsageDescription` in your `info.plist` as it's required for iOS 14 App Store submission.

> .. call the ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization method from the AppTrackingTransparency framework?

No, UWP will call `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` for you when you call `UMPConsentInformation.sharedInstance.requestConsentInfoUpdate`.

Please also notice that you need to create an IDFA message on Funding Choices website to let UWP start requesting IDFA.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it is not showing the ATT dialog on iOS on my side, only the consent-form from funding choices is shown. Maybe the AppTrackingTransparency framework is not linked properly.

Answer (score 0):

UMP is supposed to trigger the ATT dialog automatically (providing NSUserTrackingUsageDescription is configured inside your info.plist).

For me it did not, because I had requested ATT manually before. So the ATT-status always returned a value different than '.notDetermined'.
So there was no reason for UMP to request iOS to show the dialog.